# Function Keys In NeoVim are maped to letter keys automatically

Tags: neovim

I'm trying to move my work from vim8 to NeoVim.

I got an issue in NeoVim. The first 5 function keys `F1, F2, ... F5` are automatically maped to letter `'A' 'B' 'C' 'D' 'E'` and cannot be re-mapped.

This issue only occurs on terminal nvim. In **nvim-qt**, there is no problem. And the **vim8** in same environment works well. I didn't install any plugin or put any script in init.vim.

Does Anybody know how to fix it or if it is a known issue of nvim?

The nvim I indstalled is verion v0.5.0-404-g49cd750d6 which was downloaded from https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases

Below picture is the output that I tried to click from `F1` to `F12` in INSERT mod.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known bug, I created an issue sometime ago, check https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/11773

Comment: Thank you. I guess I installed nightly version. Which version is a stable version?

Comment: I also use nightly version. Current stable is 0.4.3 as far as I remember, check their website